# How do I right align a div to another div with a scroll bar, such that the first div is aligned to the content excluding the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div which is aligned to the right. Below that is another div which has cards. I want the text "Add" on the above div to be aligned with the right of the right most card. Ofcourse, Works fine till there is no scrollbar for the cards. However, when you resize the browser such that a vertical scroll bar appears on the right, the text is no longer aligned with the right of the card.

What should be done such that the "add" text is always aligned to the right of the right most card even if there is a scroll bar.

Also, when user scrolls down, i want the "add" text to remain and not scroll up.

HTML:

```
<div class="search-bar">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <div class="add">
    <p>add new</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>card 1 header <br /> Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3 <br /> Line 4 <br /> Line 5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>card 2 header <br /> Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3 <br /> Line 4 <br /> Line 5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>card 3 header <br /> Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3 <br /> Line 4 <br /> Line 5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>card 4 header <br /> Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3 <br /> Line 4 <br /> Line 5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>card 5 header <br /> Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3 <br /> Line 4 <br /> Line 5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search-bar
{
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 4em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  & input {
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 180px;
    border: solid 0.5px #bababa;
  }
}

.add {
  height: 18px;
  display: grid;
  text-align: right;
}


.cards {
  position: relative;
  top: 5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  height: 64vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1%;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

code:
https://codepen.io/manajit111/pen/wvKPMWd

Answer (score 0):

The CSS only solution I can think of, Is to include the search bar within the grid, and make use of position sticky to prevent the `Add` text from scrolling.

```css
.search-bar {
 
  /* position: relative; */
  /* top: 4em; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  
  position:sticky;    /* New */
  top:0;              /* New */
  background:white;   /* New */
  grid-column:1 / -1; /* Ensure the search-bar fill the whole row */
  grid-row:1; /* Ensure the search-bar be on the first row, Not really needed since the search-bar is the first child in the DOM tree. */
}

input {
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 180px;
  border: solid 0.5px #bababa;
}



.add {
  display: grid;
  text-align: right;
  border: solid 2px;
}
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  height: 64vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.card {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height:1000px; /* to cause overflow not needed */
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="search-bar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <div class="add">
      <p>add new</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>card 1 header <br /> Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3 <br /> Line 4 <br /> Line 5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>card 2 header <br /> Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3 <br /> Line 4 <br /> Line 5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>card 3 header <br /> Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3 <br /> Line 4 <br /> Line 5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>card 4 header <br /> Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3 <br /> Line 4 <br /> Line 5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-info">
      <p>card 5 header <br /> Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3 <br /> Line 4 <br /> Line 5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Word of advice, Don't use percentage value for margin/padding, it's difficult to maintain across multiple elements, special in grid where a grid item's parent is a track with a changing size *`minmax()`*

Comment: Thanks Zohir. Will take note of your advice..  However, this solution has 2 issues. 1. There is actually a background image for the entire page and so I cannot make the search bar background as white. So, while scrolling, the cards actually scroll into the search bar.  2. The scroll bar itself is now going till the top till the search bar, which doesnt look good and is not wanted.

Comment: @Manajit seems specific enough to use JavaScript for this, I can't think of a CSS only solution for this right now.

Comment: I agree, but no one has come up with even a javascript based solution.. thanks.